# Why the state is not updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want the alert to display lineaData.name="new Name" and lineaData.age=33 when the button is clicked, but it keeps displaying the initial values.  What wrong?

I'am using React 16.13.1

Thanks in advance.

```
  const TestComp = () => {
  const [lineaData, setLineaData] = useState({
    name: "",
    age: 0,
  });

  const [sendData, setSendData] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setSendData(true);
    alert(lineaData.name + " - " + lineaData.age);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (sendData) {
      setLineaData({
        ...lineaData,
        name: "new Name",
        age: 33,
      });
    }
  }, [sendData]);

  return (
    <Grid>
      <FormControl style={{ width: "335px" }}>
        <FormControl>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            type="text"
            label="Name:"
            name="name"
            onChange={(e) =>
              setLineaData({
                ...lineaData,
                name: e.target.value,
              })
            }
            value={lineaData.name || ""}
          />
          <FormHelperText>{lineaData.nameError}</FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
      </FormControl>

      <Button type="submit" onClick={handleClick}>
        <img src="./imagenes/ok.png" align="right|middle" height="30" alt="" />
      </Button>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

Comment: React states are async, it's unlikely `sendData` has been updated at the point you are calling the alert, let alone it having triggered and completed the update on `lineaData`

Comment: Does it not show the correct values in the form? It should be obvious that the useEffect hook hasn't run yet when you alert the values.

Comment: Any idea on how to structure the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you want to accomplish but I think you can get rid of the sendData-state and the UseEffect-hook.

Just set the state of lineaData in handleClick like so:

```js
const handleClick = () => {
    setLineaData({
        name: "new Name",
        age: 33,
    });
    alert("new Name - 33");
};
```

Besides you don't need to spread lineaData when you set all props.

Comment: The idea is to update an object before sending it to a Node back end.   When the object is update with data coming from a component event, like the textField's onChange, everything is ok.   But setting the state in handleClick is not working.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment above, you cannot tell if the state update worked by the alert right after, because state updates are asynchronous. (I edited my answer in respect of that.)  I see no reason why the state update should not work in the handleClick.

Comment: Does the value of your TextField update after you click the button?

Comment: Yes, Textfield's value is updated.   That's clear to me now.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use useEffect to get it to update. Just call setState directly in your handleClick function

```
  const handleClick = () => {
      setLineaData({
        ...lineaData,
        name: "new Name",
        age: 33,
      });
  };
```

Comment: This code doesn't works.   The first time the button is clicked, alert shows the variables in blank.   The second time it brings the values I expect.